# I'm working on a search bar but I'm wanting to add a preset url to it

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im wanting a search bar with a preset url an example of how i want this is for my url to be something like preset with youtube.com/ and after the / in my search bar a user will enter something per say CrashCourse and when they press enter it will redirect to youtube.com/CrashCourse!

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve], this question is unclear

Comment: That’s easy, just programme it after you hit search!

Comment: Try googling for `javascript string operators` and `window.location` If you're still having trouble getting it to work, please post your code.

Comment: @jayms this is more about the base tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function redirect(){
  //Get input element
  input=document.getElementById("input");
  //Redirect the user
  window.location="https://youtube.com/"+input.value;
  alert("https://youtube.com/"+input.value);
}
```

```css
/*SO relevant*/
body{
margin:0;
background:#121212;
color:white;
font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif;

}
#input{
color:white;
margin:5px;
padding:5px;
background:black;
border:1px solid grey;
}

a{color:orange;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Your styling here -->
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="input">
<a href="javascript:redirect();">Redirect me!</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are interested to set the base tag, like

```
<base href="https://www.youtube.com/" target="_blank">
```

Try it out in an online example: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Comment: Im wanting to do something like YouTube.com/ + users searchbox entry